# How to apply squeeze theorem and find the limit of the function at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Use squeeze theorem to evalute
$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ where
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{x} & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}\\ 
\frac{\sin x}{x} & \text{if } x \text{ is rational}, x\neq 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
I don't know how to do that. Now if I consider a sequence {$y_n$} of irrational for which $\lim f(y_n)$ is 2 and if {$x_n$} be a sequence of nonzero rationals then $\lim f(x_n)$ is 1. I did find this limits without using squeeze theorem but the limit is not unique here. So I get confuse how to approach for this problem and use squeeze theorem?.

Comment: What you did is ok, the problem is nonsense. Maybe a typo for $\displaystyle\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}$.

Comment: Your analysis suggests there there is no limit as $x \to 0$

Comment: Yeah I think it is a typo but anyway I have to solve it. Actually how to find this limits using squeeze theorem. For second one I think it will be sinx$\leq$x?